# Vue V-for in tables

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, html-table

I am trying to create tables using the v-for directive, but I wanted to know if there is any way to do some conditionals inside the individual tables based on a certain value. I am including a generic version of what I have as my data and what I am trying to produce.

Data Example (this is what I am pulling in from the API call):

| MainOrg | SubOrgId | SubOrgName | SubOrgState | TotalOrgs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10110 | 101101 | Main Office | AK | 26 |
| 10110 | 101102 | Branch Office | AK | 4 |
| 10110 | 101102 | Sat Office | AK | 2 |
| 10111 | 101111 | Main Office | FL | 26 |
| 10111 | 101112 | Branch Office | FL | 4 |
| 10111 | 101112 | Sat Office | FL | 2 |

I am trying to loop through the "MainOrg" column and create a new table for each unique one, then have the data that corresponds to that "MainOrg" in the output table. The "MainOrg" would become the title for the table.

The output I am trying to get is as follows:

**10110**

| SubOrgId | SubOrgName | SubOrgState | TotalOrgs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101101 | Main Office | AK | 26 |
| 101102 | Branch Office | AK | 4 |
| 101102 | Sat Office | AK | 2 |

**10111**

| SubOrgId | SubOrgName | SubOrgState | TotalOrgs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101111 | Main Office | FL | 26 |
| 101112 | Branch Office | FL | 4 |
| 101112 | Sat Office | FL | 2 |

I have been running into the following issues with the **v-for** and **v-if** directives:

**Duplicates main orgs due to it being based on index

```html
<table v-for="(d, index) in data" :key="index">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>{{ d.MainOrg }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

I really want it to spit out a new table for each unique "MainOrg", then contextually look at my data to include the "SubOrg" data that matches it, per my desired result above. I have not been able to find the right combination of Vue Html and/or JavaScript that can create the desired result based on the need for the data to be separated into individual tables. Also, within the table elements, I am unsure of how to reference the index of the data for conditionals. For example, when I tried using **v-if** instead of **v-for** to create the tables by accessing a unique array of the MainOrgs, I did not know how to contextually tie the data together.

In non-programmer speak/pseudo code: Take the unique MainOrg values from data and create a new table for each MainOrg. Then, take the remaining columns/rows from data and add them to each MainOrg table where the row context (data.MainOrg) matches the table for that MainOrg.

Apologies for the long post, but any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
I am getting slightly different results from the two answers suggested as follows:

```
computed: {
  regions: ({ estabSearchResult }) =>
    estabSearchResult.reduce(
      (map, { region, ...rest }) => ({
        ...map,
        [region]: [...(map[region] ?? []), rest],
      }),
      {}
    ),
  },
```

**Some data shown is modified for sensitivity**
Which gives me the following:

```
regions:Object
IN0110 - :Array[2]
IN0114 - :Array[1]
IN0115 - :Array[1]
IN0120 - :Array[1]
IN0130 - :Array[1]
IN0160 - :Array[1]
IN01BB - :Array[1]
IN28AO - :Array[1]
IN28BO - :Array[13]
```

The `forEach()` method(below)

```
if (this.estabSearchResult.length > 0) {
  const newObj = {}
  this.estabSearchResult.forEach(obj => {
    newObj[obj.region] ?
      newObj[obj.region].push(obj) : newObj[obj.region] = [obj]
  })
  this.estabRegionGroup = newObj
}
```

gives me the following:

```
estabRegionGroup:Object
IN0110 - :Array[3]
IN0114 - :Array[1]
IN0115 - :Array[1]
IN0120 - :Array[1]
IN0130 - :Array[1]
IN0160 - :Array[1]
IN01BB - :Array[1]
IN28AO - :Array[1]
IN28BO - :Array[13]
```

Notice the array size for IN0110. The `forEach()` gives me 3 objects in the array, where the `reduce(map())` gives me only two. All other items/regions are the same and correct, only that first one is off. Any ideas? The results for IN0110 should have 3 objects in it.

Comment: Vue v2 or v3? Options or Composition API?

Comment: Vue 2 currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a computed property to represent the new data structure

```js
computed: {
  regions: ({ estabSearchResult }) =>
    estabSearchResult.reduce(
      (map, { region, ...rest }) => ({
        ...map,
        [region]: [...(map[region] ?? []), rest],
      }),
      {} // don't forget to init with an empty object
    ),
}
```

This looks something like

```js
{
  "10110": [{ SubOrgId: 101101, ... }, ...],
  "10111": [{ SubOrgId: 101111, ... }, ...],
}
```

which you can then use in rendering

```js
// Just some fake, random data using your "region" values
const fakeApi = {get:()=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,1000,[{"region":"IN0110","foo":0.7051213449189915},{"region":"IN0110","foo":1.4213972602828675},{"region":"IN0110","foo":2.075397586536013},{"region":"IN0114","foo":0.7055750843380546},{"region":"IN0115","foo":0.5976362522109442},{"region":"IN0120","foo":0.6605446959279311},{"region":"IN0130","foo":0.7179704337235409},{"region":"IN0160","foo":0.19066097499077084},{"region":"IN01BB","foo":0.0019511615325726872},{"region":"IN28AO","foo":0.46443847116756487},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":0.41268230939585426},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":1.9572873014553014},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":2.610276341696757},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":3.7301898988777733},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":4.021495358709221},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":5.996280938563549},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":6.66092280472865},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":7.660937785660997},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":8.288195167562918},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":9.84101941796214},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":10.34450778678685},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":11.782972607317836},{"region":"IN28BO","foo":12.05067212727201}]))};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    estabSearchResult: [],
  }),
  async created () {
    this.estabSearchResult = await fakeApi.get();
  },
  computed: {
    regions: ({ estabSearchResult }) =>
      estabSearchResult.reduce(
        (map, { region, ...rest }) => ({
          ...map,
          [region]: [...(map[region] ?? []), rest],
        }),
        {}
      ),
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-if="estabSearchResult.length === 0">Loading...</p>
  <div v-for="(orgs, region) in regions" :key="region">
    <p><strong>{{ region }} ({{ orgs.length }})</strong></p>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Foo</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(org, index) in orgs" :key="index">
          <td>{{ org.foo }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I have something wrong, but when I try using the computed method and map function, my computed array gets closer but not quite right. Going to add what is getting produced and what I have the computed property set to in original question

Comment: The problem is you haven't used `...rest`

Comment: Apologies, I had a brain short and my eyes automatically translated `...rest` into my remaining data fields. This is what I get for messing with things so late. Going to try this method again and see if it performs better

Comment: Ok, follow-up question on using this computed property angle: after I fixed my mistake, it does indeed get the data in the format I need a little quicker than the other solution. However, when I compare the two, I notice the results are slightly different. I will add another edit to my post above to show what is produced by the two.

Comment: @SemiproCCXI your `reduce()` call is missing the 2nd _init_ parameter of `{}`

Comment: still getting the same result even after adding the 2nd init param of `{}`

Comment: @SemiproCCXI I cannot reproduce that ~ https://jsfiddle.net/f7k2zunL/. Both methods produce the same result

Comment: @SemiproCCXI you probably have duplicate secondary keys so you'll need to use a different `key` in the `<tr>` elements. I've changed my example to use `index`

Comment: I think it may have been a browser cache issue. When i launched locally today both methods produce same result. Computed `reduce` method is more resource efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you have to convert your `array of objects` into an `object of objects` which contains `MainOrg` as key with the help of [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Like this **:**

```js
const tableAllData = [{
  MainOrg: 10110,
  SubOrgId: 101101,
  SubOrgName: 'Main Office'
}, {
  MainOrg: 10110,
  SubOrgId: 101102,
  SubOrgName: 'Branch Office'
},{
  MainOrg: 10110,
  SubOrgId: 101102,
  SubOrgName: 'Sat Office'
}, {
  MainOrg: 10111,
  SubOrgId: 101111,
  SubOrgName: 'Main Office'
},{
  MainOrg: 10111,
  SubOrgId: 101112,
  SubOrgName: 'Branch Office'
}, {
  MainOrg: 10111,
  SubOrgId: 101112,
  SubOrgName: 'Sat Office'
}];

const newObj = {};

tableAllData.forEach(obj => {
  newObj[obj.MainOrg] ?
    newObj[obj.MainOrg].push(obj) : newObj[obj.MainOrg] = [obj]
});

console.log(newObj);
```

Live Demo with Vue **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tableAllData: [{
      MainOrg: 10110,
      SubOrgId: 101101,
      SubOrgName: 'Main Office'
    }, {
      MainOrg: 10110,
      SubOrgId: 101102,
      SubOrgName: 'Branch Office'
    },{
      MainOrg: 10110,
      SubOrgId: 101102,
      SubOrgName: 'Sat Office'
    }, {
      MainOrg: 10111,
      SubOrgId: 101111,
      SubOrgName: 'Main Office'
    },{
      MainOrg: 10111,
      SubOrgId: 101112,
      SubOrgName: 'Branch Office'
    }, {
      MainOrg: 10111,
      SubOrgId: 101112,
      SubOrgName: 'Sat Office'
    }],
    categorizedTable: {}
  },
  mounted() {
    const newObj = {};
    this.tableAllData.forEach(obj => {
      newObj[obj.MainOrg] ?
        newObj[obj.MainOrg].push(obj) : newObj[obj.MainOrg] = [obj]
    });
    this.categorizedTable = newObj;
  }
})
```

```css
table, thead, th, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in Object.keys(categorizedTable)" :key="item">
    <h3>{{ item }}</h3>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <th>SubOrgId</th>
        <th>SubOrgName</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(row, index) in categorizedTable[item]" :key="index">
          <td>{{ row.SubOrgId }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.SubOrgName }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to get me what I need, thank you! I will mark this as complete.

Comment: What happens if / when the original data changes? Calculating it in `mounted` only occurs once

Comment: @phil I actually moved it into my api call function so that after my data element is populated it takes that logic and pipes the new data into the new object. The only reason I still use the original data array is I have other dynamic objects doing some things based on that data. But now, it updates with each execution of the api call which occurs on page load or when a user clicks search with a few parameters. I marked this answer as correct since it got me there, but perhaps I should have mentioned the changes I made. Any way for me to post that or edit the original post?

Comment: OP said their data is loaded from an API so computing a copy in the `mounted` hook won't be reactive to the new data when it arrives

Comment: @Phil It will work. Once data came from an API we can assign that into the data object property.  Just for a demo purpose I used mock json

Comment: That won't matter one bit since `categorizedTable` won't be recomputed.